# Hive Table is MANAGED or EXTERNAL - issue post table type conversion

Tags: hive, external-tables, hive-table

I have a hive table in `XYZ` db named `ABC`.

When I run `describe formatted XYZ.ABC;` from hue, I get the following..

[image: MANAGED TABLE SHOWN AS EXTERNAL]

that is

```
Table Type: MANAGED_TABLE
Table Parameters: EXTERNAL True
```

So is this actually an external or a managed/internal hive table?

Comment: It looks like some bug in displaying table information. Only drop table behavior will show. external=true says it is external. But table type says it is managed. There is inconsistency. Drop table should leave location with data as is if it is EXTERNAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is treated as an `EXTERNAL` table. Dropping table will keep the underlying `HDFS` data. The table type is being shown as `MANAGED_TABLE` since the parameter `EXTERNAL` is set to `True`, instead of `TRUE`.

To fix this metadata, you can run this query:

```
hive> ALTER TABLE XYZ.ABC SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
```

**Some details:**

The table `XYZ.ABC` must have been created via this kind of query:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE XYZ.ABC
<additional table definition details>
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'EXTERNAL'='True');
```

Describing this table will give:

```
hive> desc formatted XYZ.ABC;
:
Location:               hdfs://<location_of_data>
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE
:
Table Parameters:
  EXTERNAL              True
```

Dropping this table will keep the data referenced in `Location` in `describe` output.

```
 hive> drop table XYZ.ABC;
 # does not drop table data in HDFS
```

The `Table Type` still shows as `MANAGED_TABLE` which is confusing.

Making the value for `EXTERNAL` as `TRUE` will fix this.

```
hive> ALTER TABLE XYZ.ABC SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
```

Now, doing a `describe` will show it as expected:

```
hive> desc formatted XYZ.ABC;
:
Location:               hdfs://<location_of_data>
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE
:
Table Parameters:
    EXTERNAL                TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Example -

Lets create a sample **MANAGED table**,

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TBL(abc int, xyz string);
INSERT INTO TABLE test_tbl values(1, 'abc'),(2, 'xyz');
DESCRIBE FORMATTED test_tbl;
```

[image: MANAGED_TABLE describe table image]

**Changing type to EXTERNAL *(in the wrong way using `True`, instead of `TRUE`)***:

```
ALTER TABLE test_tbl SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='True');
```

This gives,
[image: External Table Wrongly shown image]

Now lets **DROP the table**,
    DROP TABLE test_tbl;

The result:

> Table is dropped but data on HDFS isn't. Showing correct external table behavior!

If we re-create the table we can see data exists:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl(abc int, xyz string);
SELECT * FROM test_tbl;
```

Result:
[image: Output of select *]

The describe shows it wrongly as `MANAGED TABLE` along with `EXTERNAL True` because of:

[.equals check in the meta](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/ObjectStore.java#L2042)

Hive Issue JIRA: [HIVE-20057](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20057)

Proposed fix: [Use case insensitive equals](https://github.com/apache/hive/pull/388)